# How to make list view First item selected at default in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, delphi-xe

I need to set my list view fisrt item get selected by default.
how to make first item of list view selected by default in delphi?

Answer (score 6):

Select the first item in the list view like this:

```
if ListView.Items.Count > 0 then
  ListView.Selected := ListView.Items[0];
```

Do this as soon as the list view is populated.

Comment: Are you needing more help?

Comment: Does it not answer the question?